# Linux, Ubuntu & Apple Aluminium keyboard: remap greater/less with tilde

Tags: linux, keyboard, remapping, xmodmap, setxkbmap

I have an Apple Aluminium keyboard. To the left of <kbd>1</kbd> key I have the less/greater (<kbd>< ></kbd>) key, not grave/tilde (<kbd>` ~</kbd>).

`xmodmap` does not work for me: layout switching (done with `setxkbmap`) resets my xmodmap changes. `.Xmodmap` file does not help either.

How do I remap the tilde key?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## xmodmap Way

First, check [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppleKeyboard) out.

Here's my version of `.xsession`:

```
#! /usr/bin/env sh
GTK_IM_MODULE=xim
QT_IM_MODULE=xim
xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap-Apple
```

and the corresponding `~/.Xmodmap-Apple` (for the Russian version):

```
keycode 94 = grave asciitilde Cyrillic_io Cyrillic_IO
keycode 191 = Print Sys_Req Print Sys_Req Print Sys_Req
keycode 192 = Scroll_Lock NoSymbol Scroll_Lock NoSymbol Scroll_Lock
keycode 193 = Pause Break Pause Break Pause Break
keycode 49 = less greater less greater
keycode 108 = Multi_key Alt_L Multi_key Alt_L
```

## setxkbmap way

In Linux, `setxkbmap` is used to switch keyboard layouts. Alas, `setxkbmap` & `xmodmap` can't work together: they reset each other's changes :( You'll have to pick one of:

- Just don't switch layouts
- Invoke `xmodmap` after every layout switching (or make a script replacing `setxkbmap`)
- modify `xkb` key mappings for your keyboard.

We'll use the latter. First, check which layout you're using:

```
$ setxkbmap -print
xkb_keymap {
        xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
        xkb_types     { include "complete+caps(internal)"       };
        xkb_compat    { include "complete"      };
        xkb_symbols   { include "pc+us+ru:2+inet(evdev)+altwin(meta_win)+group(alt_shift_toggle)+compose(ralt)+eurosign(e)+terminate(ctrl_alt_bksp)+macintosh_vndr/apple(alupckeys)"    };
        xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc104)"     };
};
```

Here's your symbols map: `xkb_symbols ... macintosh_vndr/apple(alupckeys)`

In Ubuntu, we have a mapping for apple keyboards here: '/usr/share/X11/xkb/*symbols/macintosh_vndr/apple*'. First, backup this file. This file has several sections, each starts like this:

```
xkb_symbols "extended" {
xkb_symbols "laptop" {
xkb_symbols "laptop_bad_switch" {
xkb_symbols "alukbd" {
xkb_symbols "alupckeys" {
```

The latter mapping, `"alupckeys"`, replaces <kbd>F13</kbd>-<kbd>F15</kbd> with <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd>, <kbd>ScrollLock</kbd>, <kbd>Pause</kbd>. Use it if you lack these keys :)

Choose the section you've got from the command output above, and append the following, before the final `}` of the section:

```
    key <LSGT> { [ grave, asciitilde, grave, asciitilde ] };
};
```

Now, restart X. Yeehaw, enjoy having the tilde key on the correct place :)

This command can also help:

```
$ setxkbmap -option "apple:alupckeys" -print | xkbcomp - $DISPLAY
```

Answer (score 1):

On the Official Ubuntu Documentation there is a page dedicated to this topic: [Apple Keyboard](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppleKeyboard)

Here are listed several fixes according to your Ubuntu version.

Comment: The solution for "Natty Narwhal" worked great for me.